# Can I use ReadProcessMemory to read program memory of a process in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, process

I have this thread running within my program's process. The thread is supposed to read this process' program memory to detect, if any forbidden code injections have occurred. Now how do I get access to the program memory of the process? Can I use the

```
ReadProcessMemory();
```

function, to read the program memory if I get the process handle with ALL_ACCESS flags?
 Also is there a way to search this program memory in such way that I could limit this memory scanning to few specific method of interest or detect the base address and length for particular method?

Comment: That's for reading another process. You don't need any APIs to read your own memory. Hard to see the point when code is already read-only in Windows.

Comment: @EJP Oh, you are right.

Comment: @EJP Do you know how to locate the program memory within process then? Asking for curiosity.

Comment: You can use VirtualQueryEx to enumerate the process address space - in your case you would be looking for sections that are executable.

Comment: You can just use function addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you get process handle with READ permissions (included in PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS) you can use ReadProcessMemory() to read the memory of the target process.

What you are looking to do is called pattern scanning.  First you would use VirtualQueryEx() to find memory regions which have MEM_COMMIT as the state and do not have PAGE_NOACCESS or PAGE_GUARD as the protection type.

You loop through these memory regions using a pattern scan function to find specific signatures which you want to blacklist.

Here is the basic idea to looping through the memory

```
int main()
{
    DWORD procid = GetProcId("whatever.exe");

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION meminfo;
    unsigned char* addr = 0;

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procid);

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;

    while (VirtualQueryEx(hProc, addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)))
    {
        if (mbi.State == MEM_COMMIT && mbi.Protect != PAGE_NOACCESS)
        {
            std::cout << "base : 0x" << std::hex << mbi.BaseAddress << " end : 0x" << std::hex << (uintptr_t)mbi.BaseAddress + mbi.RegionSize << "\n";
        }
        addr += mbi.RegionSize;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc);
}
```

You can find many different pattern scanning functions to complete the job from here.